# Chibi-scheme Error with Iterator

Tags: error-handling, scheme, chibi-scheme

Anyone got any idea why chibi-scheme throws the error below while attempting to use the 
chibi-loop `up-from` function:

```
ERROR: car: not a pair: #<opcode cons>
ERROR in set-dk! on line 590 of file /usr/local/share/chibi/init-7.scm: cdr: not a pair: ()
```

I am using the syntax in the following way:

```
(import (chibi loop))

>(up-from 0 (to 20) (by 2))
```

Comment: You should post the code that causes the error

Comment: @ÓscarLópez..see my edit above. Hopefully I am using the syntax in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `up-from` standalone like that. It only works inside of a `loop` form:

```
> (loop ((for x (up-from 0 (to 20) (by 2))))
    (display x)
    (newline))
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

Comment: thnks for that straight up answer